# a word for striving to make the past the present or believe that it is the present

Tags: single-word-requests

I know this is a strange concept. But I am looking for a word that embodies the sense of "presentize". So something like this:

she strived to believe that her husband is not dead and that the past in which he resides is her present. She was ____ her past.

Comment: The usual expression is 'living in the past'. She was refusing to let go of the past.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. But I want a verb that succinctly conveys that phrase.

Comment: Yes. But I doubt there is one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Alternatiives for "living in the past" are "*retreat* or  *seek refuge* in the past".

Comment: @Graffito 'Seek refuge' wasn't a verb last time I looked, and are you really suggesting 'She was retreating her past'? Perhaps you're suggesting these as further workarounds?

Comment: You can't retreat in the past; you can retreat into it. But _She was ____ her past._ needs 'retreating into', which is not just a verb. Neither is the 'living in [the]' which I suggested, as a workaround not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

***reliving***

From oxforddictionaries.com:

> **[relive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relive)** 
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT] Live through (an experience or feeling, especially an
>   unpleasant one) again in one’s imagination or memory:
>
> he broke down sobbing as he relived the attack
>
> More example sentences:
>
> However, unless you were part of the experience and want to relive the
>   fun, you should probably pass on this one.
>
> Just reliving the feeling of his arm around me after all of these
>   years was still sending electric shocks all over my body.
>
> He stared at me with his small, observant eyes and it seemed to me as
>   if he was reliving some experience of his with his mother.

Comment: It's probably as close as one can get, but the sense of refusing to let go of  the past isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

With her memory of her husband, ..... 
She was stuck in her past.
Or end it with
Her present is her past.
She was taken by her past. 
She was controlled by her past.
She was captivated by her past. 
She was drawn in by her past. 
She was tornadoed by her past.

Hope these help or at least spawn an idea for you.
RW

Answer (score 0):

She was revisiting her past.  But that sounds like it is a temporary condition.  If she refuses to accept her new reality, then she could be "living in the past"

Answer (score 0):

She was **evoking** her past...
          educing
          bethinking
          perhaps eliciting?

Comment: Welcome to ELU SE. Good suggestions. Can you add a reference or a definition to say why you would choose these words?